# Gmaps big country labels

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I noticed for the last days, Google added big country labels to the Gmaps (http://d.pr/i/JAsN).

Is there anyway to remove *only* these labels ?

I tried

```
featureType: "administrative.country", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] }
```

But it also removed the country borders.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `elementType` to apply the style to only to specific elements:

```
{featureType: "administrative.country",
 elementType: "labels",
 stylers:     [ { visibility: "off" } ] }
```